# Can't login unless twentyfifteen theme is active

Tags: theme-development, login, bug

Yesterday, I tried to clone an online website to localhost for doing some work on my theme.

I did a fresh Wordpress install on localhost and used mysqldump for copying the remote DB to localhost. I copied my theme to `themes` and finally, I ran `UPDATE` on `site_url` and `home` in `wp_options`. This process worked fine for me a couple of times in the past.

After doing so, I couldn't log in: when I enter correct credentials, login.php redirects to itself without any error or warning. On entering incorrect credentials, I get the "bouncing" message that they're not right, as it should work.

This problem disappears when I `UPDATE` current_theme, stylesheet and template to twentyfifteen in `wp_options`.

That is, I can log in fine when twentyfifteen is activated but as soon as I activate my own theme, Wordpress asks me to log in again which I then can't anymore. Does that make any sense?

Oddly, I can see my site on localhost correctly displaying my own theme as a non logged in visitor! However, I do need the aforementioned MySQL query for setting the theme back in order to log in.

What -if anything- in my theme could cause such symptoms?

On the (OK) live version I run the Rename wp-login.php plugin. I did not install it on the problematic local site but I do see the alternative login URL in `wp_options`. It seems unlikely to me that this is related to the problem but I wanted to mention this anyway.[image: Result after attempting login]

Comment: I can't say what is different in your theme, but there are still plenty of URL's to change when you do such a migration. Run a plugin like [Velvet Blues Update URL's](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) and update all your URL's accordingly. Then flush your permalinks afterwards

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You should post your update/solution as an answer, instead of an edit. It's OK to [answer your own question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), and you can even choose to accept it after 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Because the problem is theme specific, I guessed that perhaps something in `functions.php` could be the culprit. I renamed the file to some random string and this resolved the problem.

I then experimented by commenting out sections of `functions.php`and discovered that `wp_reset_password(...)` caused the problem. I needed it only once anyway, so I removed it and I'm now living happily ever after.